# Reverse graph visualization

Tags: linux, open-source, math, image-recognition

Graph visualizers, such as Graphviz, can take a formal representation of the nodes and edges of a graph and produce an image from them. What's a program or programming library that can do the reverse; that is, recognize an image of a graph and produce a formal representation? I would be interested in software for recognizing a bitmap as well as the easier case of recognizing a graph from an SVG that follows a standard structure. Either way, restrictions on the graph's appearance are okay. Also, I require only the extraction of node-and-edge relationships, not other things like text labels of nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) and some custom code in C or python, (it is not a very common requirement).

The answers to [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/101717/visually-anayzing-network-diagrams/) question do a great job of discussing how to go about this in C.

For a ready rolled solution you might wish to take a look at [NEFI](https://github.com/05dirnbe/nefi):
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica has a built-in function called [MorphologicalGraph](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MorphologicalGraph.html).

The open source image analysis software [Fiji](https://fiji.sc/) can do this too.  The rough steps are:

- Smoothen the image if needed
- Threshold the image to make it binary
- Process -> Binary -> Skeletonize
- Analyze -> Skeleton -> Analyze Skeleton, tick Show Detailed Info. When a table comes up, save it as CSV.

Comment: Mathematica is closed-source and hence doesn't match the open-source tag, but Fiji looks like a good suggestion.

Comment: @Kodiologist It is better to spell out the requirements to avoid confusion. Tags are for categorization first, not for communicating requirements.